# how to send my activity class file to to my handler class file edittext value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

this image my handler class file.

I want to send edittext value internet file.
I create onclicklistener in my main activity class file

but how to you send data to other class.

[image]

Comment: never post image of code. Post it as text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean that you want to pass value from MainActivity class to MyHelper class so you can insert new entry to the Database, you can make insertData() public:

```
public void insertData(String name, String description, double price) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    // and the rest of your code here...
}
```

then in your MainActivity, inside onClick() method, you can call it:

```
MyHelper myHelper = new MyHelper(this);
String name = someEditText.getText().toString();
String description = otherEditText.getText().toString();
double price = 35.6;
myHelper.insertData(name, description, price);
```

cheers

Comment: Thanks ♥       its work good